# Apache VirtualHost Error 403 on Debian Squeeze (6.0)

Tags: apache-2.2, debian

I want to host multiple domains in a single server. So, i follow every steps from [this article](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/412). i change every files ownership to **www-data:www-data** and change every files permission to **0777**

everytime i try to access http://mydomain.com/index.html, it turns out to be "ERROR 403 Forbidden", and when i look into error.log, it says "client denied by server configuration:"

Comment: Can you provide the server configuration that you've set up per that article?  Also, can you show us the output of `apache2ctl -S`?

Comment: here's the output from `apache2ctl -S` http://paste.debian.net/181415/

Comment: and here's my virtualhost configuration http://paste.debian.net/181417/

Comment: mode 777 is a horrible, horrible idea by the way. it's a basic tenet of security that www-data should *not* be able to write to anything in its doc root unless *absolutely* necessary

Comment: @Keith yes, i absolutely know that, i did that in order to make sure everyone can access it, but even though i chmod-ed it to 777 it still not working

Answer (score 2):

From your configuration, you have:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/XXXXXX.com
```

But, access to a directory can't be assumed.  You should be granting access to it in order to serve resources from it.

Add a config like this within that same `<VirtualHost>` block:

```
<Directory /var/www/XXXXXX.com>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: it's still not working :(

Comment: check to make sure that the permissions on /var/www itself are correct (e.g., 755 perhaps)

Comment: @DXX Did you restart the Apache service after making the configuration change?  Is it still the same "denied by server config" message in the log?

Comment: You may also want to change the ownership to www-data on the directory which <Directory> is pointing to.